# Can I switch off the Auto Manipulation when using Transform Hotkeys?

Tags: 3d-view, transforms, 3d-manipulator

I'm new to Blender and one thing I'm really bothered by is when using the Transform Hotkeys (G,R,S) it immediately starts manipulating my selected object with the mouse movement. Coming from Maya and C4D this behavior is rather different and not something I can see myself needing too often. Is there a way to change it so that when I press one of Hotkeys it just changes to that tool without the manipulation?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the native shortcuts for setting the tool to move rotate or scale. If you hit <kbd>alt</kbd> and release it and immediately after that hit the key for any operator, you will likely select the matching tool. This works with many things like <kbd>b</kbd> for border select, or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> for bevel in edit mode and so on, and it includes <kbd>g</kbd>,<kbd>r</kbd>,<kbd>s</kbd> as well.

**Warning! This may contain some amount of personal opinion from this point. :)** But I think there is some logic in it as well.

In general I would recommend to try and see if you can get used to Blender's way with features that are different from the package that you are used to. This is not because they would be better in any way or something like that, but because they may work better together with other parts of Blender because some workflows may differ from other software and you might be pleasantly surprised after you get used to them. Of course there will be things that you will want to customise and there is nothing wrong with making them as they are in other packages, I would just like to recommend not to rush too much so you know for sure that it's going to be more efficient for you to work in one way or another. I was surprised with many things when transitioning from Maya and am glad I gave them a chance for a bit longer than I wanted at first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the transformation tools in the Toolbar (T). If you want to assign hotkeys to these tools, right click on them and then "Change Shortcut".

[image]

Comment: I would not recommend changing the shortcut especially for someone coming from another 3d package. this just prevents learning intended workflows and may in the end be slower and less efficient.

Comment: Thanks but the problem is not the Hotkey itself as they already have assigned keys (G, R, S). The problem is in the behavior after pressing the Hotkey.

Comment: The behavior is very useful in many situations, so It really pays off to stick with it for a while, but you can use other features to work as you are used to with tools instead of operators.